# Why this warning?

Tags: exit-relays

Get this warning every time. Started a couple of months ago. Googled around but didn't find anything useful.

System:

```
Nov 11 09:06:53.748 [notice] Tor 0.3.1.8 (git-868c1b2b1eb7225a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2l, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma 5.1.0alpha, and Libzstd N/A.
Nov 11 09:12:25.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
Nov 11 09:12:33.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
Nov 11 09:13:22.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
Nov 11 09:15:50.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
Nov 11 09:17:28.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
Nov 11 09:25:27.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
Nov 11 09:26:51.000 [warn] Tried to establish rendezvous on non-OR circuit with purpose Acting as rendevous (pending)
```

Any suggestions or links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a longer discussion at [#15618](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15618) in [Tor's bug tracker](https://trac.torproject.org/). It seems that this message occurs when someone tries to call `circuit has_opened()` two times. So far it seems unclear if someone does this for some "strange" reasons or if this is a bug in Tor (see also [#21084](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21084)).

In both tickets developers try to find out more. If you can help with further clues, please add something to the bug tracker. If not, keep an eye to your log file and regularly update your Tor software. Currently it seems there is not much more you can do.